# what is the best way to return a string in C++ where size of string already known?

Tags: c++, string

When I am using str[] I get compilation error of mismatch type.When I use str+push_back instead of str[] everything works fine.

```
   class Solution {
public:
   string bits(int n){
       string str[32];//size already known thats why used str[32]
        for(long long int i=31;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(n & 1<<i){
                str[i]=('1');
            }else{
                str[i]=('0');
            }
            
        }
       return str;
    };
    int findMaximumXOR(vector<int>& nums) {
        queue<int>q;
        vector<string>s(nums.size());
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++ ){
           s[i]=bits(nums[i]);
            cout<<s[i]<<"\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: `string str[32];` is an array of 32 `string`s named `str`. It's not a `string` with 32 characters. `std::string` handles memory management for you. Just declare a `std::string str;` and call it a day. Alternative constructors [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) if you want to create it with a certain size.

Comment: In this case `str[i]` refers to `string` #i in that array of strings. You end up trying to assign a `char` to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string str[32];` is declaring an *array* of 32 `std::string` objects.  But the `bits()` method is declared as returning a single `std::string`, which is why `return str;` does not work.

You don't want an array of 32 strings.  You want a single string of 32 characters in length, eg:

```cpp
std::string bits(int n) {
    std::string str(32, '0');
    for(long long int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (n & (1 << i)) {
            str[i] = '1';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

That being said, As @Slava mentioned in comments, if you want a *better* way, use [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead:

```cpp
std::string bits(int n) {
    return std::bitset<32>(n).to_string();
}
```

Comment: A string filled with NUL?

Comment: @tadman if you want to allocate up front in one line you have to fill it with something. OP has a comment about setting the array to 32 because they know how many characters they need. Looks like a leethaxxorchef.ru website thing so performance matters.

Comment: If performance matters, fill it with `'0'` so you don't need to do anything for those. On average 50% less work!

Comment: Seems like wasted effort. You know it's going to be `'1'` or `'0'`, there's no ambiguity there, so pick one and pre-fill it. Then just skip those during the iteration.

Comment: If you want style points: `str[i] = (n & 1 << i) >> i + '0'`

Comment: @tadman actually if `str` is filled with '0' it allows: `for(int i = 31; n; i--, n >>= 1 ) str[i] = (n & 1) + '0';` :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Loving it! I'm only persnickety about `'\0'` because that's an invisible character and can lead to strange output that looks valid, but is actually garbage.

Comment: @Slava You're on to something: `str[i] += n & 1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a string representing a 32-bit binary expression you need a single string. In C++ `[]` in a declaration generally refers to an *array of something*, as in `int x[N]` is an array of *N* `int` values.

Reworked:

```cpp
  string bits(int n) {
    std::string str(32, '0'); // Reserve with 32 x 0

    for(long long int i=31;i>=0;i--) {
      if(n & 1<<i) {
          str[i]=('1');
      }
    }

    return str;
  };
```

There's a *lot* of quirks in this code, too, which I'll remove here:

```cpp
  // Avoid using namespace std; and embrace the std:: prefix
  std::string bits(int n) {
    string str(32, '0');

    // You do not need a long long int to iterate to 31
    // Also try and express your loops as going from 0..N-1 unless
    // doing so overly complicates the code.
    for (int i=0; i<32; ++i) {
      // Although not necessary, the brackets around (1 << i)
      // make it abundantly clear this is not to be read as
      // something like (n & 1) << i
      if (n & (1 << i)) {
        // The braces around the '1' serve no purpose
        str[i]='1';
      }
    }

    return str;
  };
```

Comment: Or simply one line: `return std::bitset<32>( n ).to_string();`

Comment: @Slava Yeah, if doing so is permitted. This looks like an assignment.

Comment: OP is asking for the best way, nothing about restrictions

Comment: @Slava The `Solution` name of the class suggests to me it's an assignment, but your point is valid.